# Algorithm to find exactly two sets of numbers that have the same sum

Tags: algorithms

I am searching for the most efficent implementation of a specific algorithm:

Assume you have a set of positive integers, for example:

X = [1,1,2,3,3,6,8]

The aim is to find exactly two sets (containing together all elements of X), so that the sum of all elements of the one is equal to the sum of the other.

So for example a solution would be (there can be more than one solution of course, or no solution):
A = [1,2,3,6]
B = [1,3,8]

(Sorry if my wording is wrong, just a curious developer and no computer scientist)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is called the [Partition Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_problem), and it's NP-complete, meaning that it's very unlikely that any algorithm can solve every instance of the problem quickly. On the bright side, if there are $n$ numbers and their total sum is $t$, there is a fairly simple $O(nt)$-time dynamic programming algorithm (see section "Pseudo-polynomial time algorithm" on that webpage), and this is fast enough to solve many practical instances.

Comment: I checked now the algorithm found on the Wiki, I understand that the algorithm can tell me whether the set S can be partitioned into two subsets that have equal sum - but it doesn't tell me which elements of S concretely are in those sets, or does it?

Comment: You can extract a concrete set of elements by "tracing back" through the dynamic programming (DP) matrix (a standard DP technique).  Every matrix cell corresponds to a state, and for this problem every state has either 1 or 2 possible predecessor states; given some particular state $P[i, j]$, you can test which of the two possible predecessor states $P[i-x_i, j-1]$ or $P[i, j-1]$ could have given rise to it: at least one of them must be true; the former indicates $x_i$ is part of an optimal solution.  In this way you can trace backwards from the final state $P[t, n]$.

Comment: ok managed to implement it, thanks, really learned something here

Comment: Glad to hear it!  DP is a cool technique I think :)